# Find all of open SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, sqlconnection

I read and write data to Sql Server on another server and because of it i need to open many `SqlConnection`, i close them after read or write finished,but sometimes i can't connect to server but after i restart the server every thing is ok,i guess that it's because of that some `SqlConnection` was open,is there any way that i can find all of them if exist?

Comment: Please post the connection code...

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "no". The only way you could do this would be to explicitly add your own tracking code, but then what you are *actually* doing is risking *holding onto them for longer*, plus it is likely that you'd forget to add it in the 2 places where you are already forgetting to close things.

The preferred "fix" here is : stop worrying about *closing* things, and start `using` them instead. If you use `using` **every** time you touch a connection, you *cannot* forget to release it.

```
using(var conn = whatever.GetOpenConnection()) {
    // ... do stuff
} // <=== here it will be disposed for us automatically, success or failure
  // and disposable includes Close()
```

This applies equally to *any* types that implement `IDisposable`. In the case of ADO.NET, that includes commands and readers too.